# Windows Universal Application Bing Maps Integration

Tags: win-universal-app, bing-maps

I try to integrate Bing Maps to my Windows Universal Application.

I added this namespace;

```
xmlns:maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
```

After that;

```
<maps:MapControl x:Name="myMap" ZoomLevel="5"  MapServiceToken="{value get from Bing Maps Portal}">
</maps:MapControl>
```

"myMap" does not show anything. Is there anything i should do additionally. In internet there is lack of tutorials, all the tutorials are about Windows 8.1 Phone development.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop your application using Windows Mobile Emulator, Bing maps is not working. To tackle this issue, temporarily test and debug your application as desktop application, instead of using mobile emulator.